# User-specific timer actions in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have a database full of users and each user has timestamps for a specific events they've executed. I would like to fire off an action for each individual user based on their timestamps. So for example: user1 hasn't logged in for 5 days, send her an email or put her user status to "idle" mode.

What would be the best way about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way but usually you setup [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs to that kind of things.

Your cron job would be a simple PHP script, it would query the database to find all the users that the system should process and send emails etc ...

If you are on windows the scheduled task should be a drop in replacement for cron jobs.

Comment: If I have a cron job running every 5 days, and the user signs up in the middle of those 5 days then there is a lag between her official event firing and the cron job actually firing the event. Unless I run the cron job more often than every 5 days. But if I made the time intervals to be in minutes and not days, then wouldn't this take up a lot of processing? Is there a user-listener that I can setup without running a script that checks the whole user records? In the end, my main concern is performance.

Comment: @samxli: I don't know how many users you have, I would setup the job everyday and make sure to process only the subset of users I need to. If you see your cron jobs begin to be too long you can start thinking of another solution. After the cron job you would have to create your own daemon and it would a lot more complicated.

Comment: any other alternatives than using cron jobs?

Comment: @samxli: make a daemon, why you cannot use cron job?